# Simple question but, can I find if these two matrices are similar by doing it's determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra

> "Show that A and B are not similar"
>
> \begin{align}A&=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\0&1&2\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\\\\
> > B&=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&0\\\frac12&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\end{align}

Can I just look if the determinants are the same here? All the solutions for the 2x2 matrices were used by comparing determinants but for the 3x3 matrices all the solutions used rank comparison or more complex solutions. Is there anything wrong with just finding the determinants of them and comparing them, is it just a matter of preference?

Comment: If the determinants differ, then the matrices are not similar. If the determinants are equal, they may or may not be similar.

Comment: Second matrix: $1^{\text{st}}$ and $2^{\text{nd}}$ column are proportional $\implies\det=0$ How is finding the rank complex?

Answer (score 1):

Recall that two matrices $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ are similar if there exists an invertible $T \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ s.t. $A = T B T^{-1}$.

Hence $$\det(A) = \det(T B T^{-1}) = \det(T) \det(B) \det(T^{-1}) = \det(B)$$

So in order to show that two matrices are not similar it is enough to show that their determinant differs.

---

I would guess that you did not use the determinant for $3 \times 3$ matrices since they are harder to compute, than for the $2 \times 2$ case. On the other hand, seeing that one matrix has different rank than the other is also enough, since multiplying by invertible matrices preserves rank; and (can be) easier for the $3 \times 3$ (or $n \times n$) case.

In this particular case, either method works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For simlar matrices $A$ and $B$ $(A=PBP^{-1})$, $\det|A|=\det|B|$. and Trace(A)=Trace(B).

In your case one can quickly check that $\det|A|=1$ but $\det |B|=0$.
So $A$ and $B$ cannot be similar.